# Send HTML file as email from Access

Tags: html, ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I'd like to use VBA to send an HTML file as an email. Basically, is there a way "pull" the HTML code from a file as a variable for the .HTMLBody property in Access?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In VBA you can [Open](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264163%28v=office.14%29.aspx) a text file and then use [Line Input #](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264130%28v=office.14%29.aspx) statements to read lines from it. Or, if you wanted to use a [TextStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264514%28v=office.14%29.aspx) object you could use the `.ReadAll` method to read the whole thing in one shot.

Comment: Ok. Thanks. I'll look into that. Do you know if I would be able to use a Replace() function around that stream of text?

Comment: @user3177831 Once you've read the text into a `String` variable you should be able to use `Replace()` and other string functions on it.